# Is there a fast way to jump to element using XMLReader?

Tags: php, performance, large-files, xmlreader

I am using XMLReader to read a large XML file with about 1 million elements on the level I am reading from.  However, I've calculated it will take over 10 seconds when I jump to -for instance- element 500.000 using `XMLReader::next  ([  string $localname  ] )` or `XMLReader::read  ( void  )`

This is not very usable. Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: One way would be not to use XML, but an efficient and indexed binary format. Or a database.

Comment: The files are supplied by a third party. Unfortunately they have no other way to retrieve the data I need (which I insert in a database).

Comment: My point was, if you need fast random access, you should convert the data. If all you're doing is inserting the data into a database, does it really matter if it takes a while? Also, why are you skipping over so many elements?

Comment: I can only do a bunch of elements at a time due to script runtime limits my hosting has. It's not a disaster, the updating (done only once) will just take an extra day or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a fast way to do this. XML is inherently slow for random accesses, and there's no way around it.

The right thing to do is to think about your algorithm and decide why you're handling the data like this. Getting from one element to the next child or sibling element is cheap and fast. As long as your algorithm only has to go over the XML file once, you shouldn't incur much overhead. However, it sounds like you may be trying to access elements out-of-order, at arbitrary places in the structure. That will be slow as molasses no matter what reader you try to use.

Comment: I'll flag this as the right answer. Thank you Matti Virkkunen and JS Bangs.

Answer (score 0):

are you allow to modify the database? If you can, I would add a  tag and then use ReadToFollowing to jump to the point.